# JavaMelody with Spring Boot and Hikari DataSource

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-melody

I'm installing javamelody in springboot projet (according to this tutorial: https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/SpringBootStarter : installation without spring-boot-starter) but when runnig server.

In application.yml file, I add 
 aop:
        proxy-target-class: true
but still not working.

Help please.
I got this error:

```
"2017-07-07 14:55:20.582 WARN 10056 --- [ restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.DelegatingMetricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setMetricsConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hikariDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'dataSource' is expected to be of type 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy132'
2017-07-07 14:55:20.585 ERROR 10056 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Destroy method on bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7d8e76e9: startup date [Fri Jul 07 14:55:14 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:954)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
at net.viamedis.kalivia.osteo.KaliviaOsteoApp.main(KaliviaOsteoApp.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

The bean 'dataSource' could not be injected as a 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:
javax.sql.DataSource
java.io.Closeable

Action:

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @enableasync and/or @enablecaching."
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was to define the HikariDataSource bean manually, thus you do *not* need to set `proxy-target-class=true`:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
    return (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
}
```

And then changing the property `url` to `jdbc-url` in the application.yml.
I also added the following configuration for javaMelody:

```
javamelody:
  enabled: true
  spring-monitoring-enabled: true
  init-parameters:
    log: true
    authorized-users: admin:********
```

Now, javaMelody is working and the Spring Boot app starts correctly.
Dependency is `"net.bull.javamelody:javamelody-spring-boot-starter:1.68.1"`

*Hint:* if your unit tests are broken after adding javaMelody, just disable it completely for your unit tests via an application profile.